# Modular equation and logarithms

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I am supposed to find out for which $n \in \mathbb{N}$
$$2^{2^{2^{2n-1}}}\equiv16\mod{127}$$

It is apparent that $16=2^{2^2}$ so I get
$$2^{2^{2^{2n-1}}}\equiv 2^{2^2} \mod{127}$$
But now, I am not sure whether I can just go ahead and take the logarithm to get
$$2n-1\equiv1 \mod{127}$$
It this allowed? To be exact, I was unable to find enough resources on this kind of equations, so If anyone has a few links available, I'd love to be able to read them.

Comment: Well, be careful.  Remember that, for primes $p$ we have $a^b\equiv a^c\pmod p$ when $b\equiv c\pmod {p-1}$, not when $b\equiv c\pmod p$.

Comment: @lulu Thank you for your answer. Is there a resource where I can find the proof of your claim? It is not apparent to me

Comment: This is Fermat's Little Theorem.  $a^{p-1}\equiv 1\pmod p$ if $\gcd (a,p)=1$.  Still assuming $p$ is prime.

Comment: To your original problem:  I suggest working examples.  Granted, the calculations get messy unless you can use modular arithmetic to reduce the exponents.  Maybe start by solving $2^k\equiv 16 \pmod {127}$.  That one is easy (why?).

Comment: @lulu If we have two numbers, a and p, and we know that p is prime, their gcd is automatically 1, no? Still, I don't see how we can arrive from $a^{p−1}≡1(\mod{p})$ to $a^b \equiv a^c (\mod{p})$.

Comment: No, $p$ might divide $a$.  If $b\equiv c \pmod {p-1}$ then $b=c+(p-1)n$ for some integer $n$.  Thus $a^b=a^ca^{(p-1)n}\equiv a^c\times 1^n\equiv a^c\pmod p$.

Comment: @lulu By this logic, I did this: 127 is a prime number, so in order for my first equation to be true, the following must be true: $2n-1 \equiv 1 \mod{126}$ This is, however, not true, because $2n$ is not congruent with $2$ when dividing by 126. But I know the statement to be true, so I don't know where a mistake has been made.

Comment: You have not shown that the initial congruence implies $2n-1\equiv 1\pmod {126}$.  You are trying to skip a lot of steps and it is getting you confused.  I told you where to start.  Solve $2^k\equiv 16\pmod {127}$.  Go from there.  And work some examples!  Take $n=2$ for instance.  That's really not so hard.

Comment: @lulu thank you for the time you've given me, I am still unsure about how to proceed. I can see that $2^k \equiv 16 \mod{127}$ means that $16+l\cdot 127 = 2^k$. Still, I don't know how to approach this problem, google did not help me.

Comment: If that problem is too hard for you, I don't see how you could approach the one you asked about.  This one can be solved mentally.  What is the order of $2\pmod {127}$?

Comment: @lulu What do you mean by order? Note that I am not from an english speaking country so the math translations might be difficult to find.

Comment: I don't know how to help you here.  Maybe it is a language issue, but it seems to me that you need to review the basics of modular arithmetic.  Start with much easier problems than the one you asked about.  Good luck!

Comment: @lulu Thank you for your time, I will do some more excercises.

Comment: I think you treat $2^{2^{2^x}}$ as $((2^2)^2)^x$ which is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that $2^7\equiv 1\pmod{127}$, and $7$ is the smallest natural number with this property. So $2^x\equiv 16 \pmod{127}$ iff $x\equiv 4 \pmod 7$. Thus you need to find out when $2^{2^{2n-1}}\equiv 4\pmod 7$. Or $2^{2^{2n-1}-2}\equiv 1 \pmod 7$. Note that $2^3\equiv 1\pmod 7$ and $3$ is the smallest possible, so $2^x\equiv 1\pmod 7$ iff $3\mid x$. Thus you need to find all $n$ such that $3\mid 2^{2n-1}-2$. That happens iff $2n-1\equiv 1\pmod 2$ which is always true.

**Answer** For every natural number $n$.

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't see how $2^7\equiv 1\pmod{127}$ implies that $2^x\equiv 16\pmod{127}$ iff $x\equiv 4\pmod{7}$. I've been looking for resoursec regarding similar questions but to no success.

Comment: $x=7q+r$ (division with remainder), so $2^x\equiv 2^r\pmod{127}$, the only possible natural $r<7$ such that $2^r\equiv 16\pmod{127}$ is $r=4$. So $x\equiv 4\pmod 7$.

Comment: I have many questions:
Why does $x$ need to equal $7q+r$? Moreover, why does the next equation need to be written as $2^x \equiv 2^r)  \pmod{127}$. I don't see why they need to be that way. I also don't see why it is is important to see that $2^7 \equiv 1 \pmod{127}$

Comment: What are the questions?

Comment: I spent the entire evening studying and finally understood your answer. Thank you for taking your time and for correcting the answer above this one.

Answer (score -1):

Putting $2^{2^{2n-1}}=X$ we have $2^X\equiv2^4\pmod{127}\Rightarrow2^{X-4}\equiv1\pmod{127}$. Then because $127$ is prime $X-4=126m$ (Fermat's L. T.). This implies $m\ge2$ and $4|X$.

Consequently $X=2^{2^{2n-1}}$ must be divisible by $4$ and $n\ge1$

Comment: "Then because $127$ is prime $X-4=126m$ (Fermat's L. T.)." That  is not true. For this $2$ should be a primitive root of $127$ which is wrong.

Comment: You never use the fact that $2n-1$ is odd. The statement is not true if you replace $2n-1$ by $2n$. $2^{2^{2^2}}=2^{16}\equiv 4\pmod{127}$.

Comment: @markvs: FOR ALL $a$ coprime with $127$ you do have $a^{126}=1$ in the corresponding prime field.

Comment: And $a^{126000}=1$ too.

Comment: @marrkvs: When is it possible to replace $2n-1$ by $2n$?

Comment: ?????${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: @Good by markvs.